# Polymer.dom :scope query selector for dom-elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

See this [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/aXdbikPp6ALhhyg17JEa/)

```
  <my-parent id="parent">
    <span id='1'>"Some Text"</span>
    <span id='2'>"Some Text"</span>
    <span id='3'>"Some Text"</span>
    <span id='4'>"Some Text"</span>
  </my-parent>
```

In my-parent's created callback ::-

```
Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('span').length   ==>  4 

Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll(':scope > span').length   ==> 0 ???
```

Does `:scope` selector not work for Polymer.dom's `querySelector` ?

Answer (score 0):

I used your element, and this works:

```
<dom-module id="my-parent">

  <template>
    <content id="myContent" select="span"></content><!--filter elements using select tag-->
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-parent",
      created: function() {//I think created function is from Polymer 0.5, Im not sure if is correct to use in Polymer 1.0
        var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
        var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
        var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
        var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");

        result1.textContent = "Selector used [Polymer.dom(this)]:: 'span'  --> " + Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('span').length;

        result2.textContent = "Selector used [Polymer.dom(this)]:: ':scope > span'  --> " + Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll(':scope > span').length;

        result3.textContent = "Selector used [this]:: 'span'  --> " + this.querySelectorAll('span').length;
        result4.textContent = "Selector used [this]:: ':scope > span'  --> " + this.querySelectorAll(':scope > span').length;


      },
      ready: function(){
        var distributed = this.getContentChildren('#myContent');//get children of content
        console.log(distributed);//show all spans
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-distribution) you can find an explanation about this topic.

Comment: However Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll(':scope > span').length still returns 0. So is scoped selector not supported ?